# How to do Logout function? Node.js MySQL Express with JWT Token

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, jwt

**Greetings!**

**I need help. Currently, my code contains Sign-up and Login function. But that's it.**

**NOTE: I couldn't paste the Signup code since its not much of a problem. But here's the work of mine to see how my signin works.**

```
exports.login = (req, res) => {
    try {
        //const {email, password} = req.body;
        const email = req.body.email;
        const password = req.body.password;   

        if(!email || !password) {
            return res.send("<script> alert('Provide an email and/or Password'); window.location='/login'; </script>");
        }
        con.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], async(error, results) => {
            console.log(results);
            if(!results || !(await bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password))) {
                return res.send("<script> alert('Email or Password is incorrect'); window.location='/login'; </script>");
            }
            else {
                const id = results[0].id;
                const token = jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
                    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
                });

                console.log("The token is: " + token);
                const cookieOptions = {
                    expires: new Date(
                        Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
                    ),
                    httpOnly: true
                }
                req.session.login = true;
                req.session.email = email;
                res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);
                res.status(200).redirect('/profile');
            }
        });
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

**This is the part that I need help.
I can't logout after I login and my exports.logout function is not working.
Is there something wrong with it?**

```
//Logout Session for USER
exports.logout = (req,res) => {
    req.session.destroy((err) =>{
       res.redirect('shop/signin');
    })
};
```

**So this is my profile.ejs. I want to call the /logout function, but I don't know... how.**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 mt-5">
            <p class="headline2">Welcome, User!</p>

            <h1><a href="/logout">Log out</a></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are destroying the session, Not the cookie where the token is stored in.
Try this,

```
exports.logout = (req,res) => {
    res.clearCookie('jwt');
    res.redirect('shop/signin');
};
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I will try this.

Comment: Just try this and mark the answer accepted if it is working. Because it worked for me.

Comment: "Cannot GET /logout". Probably there's something wrong with my "profile.ejs"

Comment: It might be some error specifying your logout route in ejs. Check where the logout controller is defined in. Check if it is only /logout or /shop/logout.